# Error: hide list View child Item

Tags: android, expandablelistview

i have ListView with childItems.when i press ListView Child item's got ImageView  when i press on it i want to remove the Expandable ListView item.please find below the code snipped i used.

code snippet i used to hide list item

```
ExpandableListView  remov = (ExpandableListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    remov.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    removimg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    addcadschildadoptor.remove(1);
    addcadschildadoptor.notify();

    }
    });

    return false;
    }
    });

    return v;
    }
```

I used Expandable list Adopter snippet

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void prepareListData() {

listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

listDataHeader.add("");

addcadschildadoptor = new ArrayList<String>();

if(cardNameone!="")
{
addcadschildadoptor.add(cardNameone);
}


if(cardNametwo!="")
{
addcadschildadoptor.add(cardNametwo);

}
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), cardNametwo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), addcadschildadoptor);

listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader,listDataChild);

expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


}
```

Error log

```
 04-04 16:47:51.611: E/InputEventReceiver(13452): Exception dispatching 
    input event.
    04-04 16:47:51.626: E/MessageQueue-JNI(13452): 
    Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
    04-04 16:47:51.696:
    E/MessageQueue-JNI(13452): java.lang.NullPointerException
    04-04 16:47:51.696: 
    E/MessageQueue-JNI(13452): at com.compareCr.ListvCompare$4.onTouch(ListvCompare.java:720)
    04-04 16:47:51.696: 
    E/MessageQueue-JNI(13452): at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7374)
    04-04 16:47:51.696: 
    E/MessageQueue-JNI(13452): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2464)

    04-04 16:47:51.696: E/MessageQueue-JNI(13452): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2197)

    04-04 16:47:51.696: E/MessageQueue-JNI(13452): at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.
    java:2470)
    04-04 16:47:51.696: E/MessageQueue-JNI(13452): 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2169)
    04-04 16:47:51.696: E/MessageQueue-JNI(13452): 
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2470)
```

Comment: please post all logcat error

Comment: removing  seems to be null

Answer (score 1):

you are using the wrong function.

> public final void notify ()
>
> Added in API level 1 Causes a thread which is waiting on this object's
>   monitor (by means of calling one of the wait() methods) to be woken
>   up. If more than one thread is waiting, one of them is chosen at the
>   discretion of the VM. The chosen thread will not run immediately. The
>   thread that called notify() has to release the object's monitor first.
>   Also, the chosen thread still has to compete against other threads
>   that try to synchronize on the same object.

Instead of notify(), You need to use

```
addcadschildadoptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Also, instead of using .setOnClickListener() on your view, you should use .setOnItemClickListener() as it gives. you extra information about the position of the item in the list. Look at the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) for more info